# Not able to Launch agent by connecting it to the master using docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in docker container and i am trying to launch slave agent by connecting it to master. I have created a slave node as docker1 and downloaded the agent.jar in my system. After running the command i am getting this error:

```
 Failed to obtain http://localhost:8080/computer/DOCKER1/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
    java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://localhost:8080/computer/DOCKER1/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true: 404 Not Found
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:515)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:347)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:298)
```

Jenkins version:2.319
i have already mapped the port to 8080 and 5000.

Comment: By default Jenkins uses 50000 instead of 5000. Maybe this helps.